# Sort alphabetically into different files

Tags: files, sort

I have a file which I am sorting alphabetically.  That is simple:  cat {some file} | sort > {newfile}

But, I need to sort if alphabetically, by the 3rd column in the file, and each letter will go into its own file.

So:  a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, etc.......

Any possible way to script this?

Comment: Could you give an example of the contents of "some file"?

Comment: Think "filtering" (grep etc.) instead of "sorting". Make a loop to do this for each letter.

Comment: So, just a simple pipe delimited file:  field1|field2|field2.   I just need so actually sort be the 4th column of field 1.   And each letter goes into its own file.  So, a possible 26 files would be created.....

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add that information?

Answer (score 3):

```
sort file | awk '{print > substr($0, 3, 1) ".txt"}'
```

Will print each line into a file whose name is the third character on the line followed by `.txt`.

Comment: This appears to work well.   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Extending @StephaneChazelas post

```
sort -k1.3 | awk '{print > substr($0, 3, 1) ".txt"}'
```

Will actually sort the lines from the 3rd character right. In other words, it will ignore the first two characters on each line when doing the `sort` before `awk`ing them out.